# How i can remove directory in linux via cli

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, archlinux

How i can remove my entire directory via cli. example i have

```
/home/user/mydoc/project.
```

is there any suggestion or guide how to do it

I need it to write php command to remove directory via ssh connection.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rm -r /home/user/mydoc/project`.

For ssh command via PHP:

```
<?php
   $connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
   ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

   $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/bin/rm -r /home/user/mydoc/project');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rm` command: `rm -r /home/user/mydoc/project`. See `man rm`.

A command to remove remote directory via SSH may look like the following:

```
ssh user@domain.com -- rm -r /home/user/mydoc/project
```

If you want to bypass interactive mode when removing files with restricted permissions owned by another user (not `user` that is used in the command above), you can use `-f` option: `rm -r -f path`.